# How can I prove that $\sup\{\Phi(f):f\in \bar B\}=1$ if $\bar B=\{f\in C\left([0,1]\right): d(f,0)\leq 1\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

> let me consider the metric $$d(f,g)=\max\left\{|f(t)-g(t)|:t\in [0,1]\right\}$$ for all $f,g, \in C\left([0,1]\right)$. Define also $$\Phi:C\left([0,1]\right)\rightarrow \Bbb{R};~~~f\mapsto |f(1)|-\int_0^1|f(t)|dt$$
> Define $\bar B=\{f\in C\left([0,1]\right): d(f,0)\leq 1\}$, then I need to show that $$\sup\{\Phi(f):f\in \bar B\}=1$$

I have done the following:

1. Step: I need to show that $\Phi(f)\leq 1$ for all $f\in \bar B$. Indeed $$\Phi(f)=|f(1)|-\int_0^1|f(t)|dt\leq |f(1)|\leq 1$$ using in the first inequality that $\int_0^1 |f(t)|dt\geq 0$ and in the second that $d(f,0)\leq 1$.
2. Step: I need to show that there is no smaller upper bound. Therefore I picked $\epsilon >0$. Assuming $1-\epsilon$ is a smaller upper bound should give a contradiction. But somehow I don't get to this contradiction. I thought about chosing an explicit $f$, maybe a constant so that $|f(1)|+\epsilon<1+\int_0^1 |f(t)|dt$ gives a contradiction.

Is the first step correct and if yes how can I do the second step?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 is correct. For Step 2 you can consider functions in $\bar B$ with $f(1) = 1$ and $\int_0^1 |f(t)| dt$ arbitrarily small, for example
$$
 f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
 0 & 0 \le x \le 1-1/n \\
 n x - n + 1 & 1-1/n \le x \le 1 \\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So e.g. I can chose $f_2(x)$ such that $f_2(x)=1-2x$ for $0\leq x\leq 1/2$ and $0$ on $1/2\leq x\leq 1$ and this should work

Comment: @Haveaniceday: You need to consider all functions $f_n$. Compute $\Phi(f_n)$ and see what happens for $n \to \infty$.

Comment: does it converge to $0$?

Comment: Sorry why do you have a $1$ there because $f_n(1)=0$?

Comment: @Haveaniceday: My fault. For some reason, I hade mixed up $f(0)$ and $f(1)$. Should be correct now.

Comment: I will try it and write what I get.

Comment: so it gives 1 and this is a contradiction

Comment: Sorry to ask here again but does this point I showed helped me to prove that $\bar B$ if I know that $\Phi$ is continuous?

Comment: @Haveaniceday: Sorry, I do not understand your question. You have already shown that $1$ is an upper bound. On the other hand, $\Phi(f_n) = 1-1/(2n)$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$ shows that there is no smaller upper bound.

Comment: No sorry I meant does the fact that $\sup\{\Phi(f):f\in \bar B\}$ and the fact that $\Phi$ is continuous help me to deduce that $\bar B$ is not compact? Because This is the next exercise somehow and I don't see why this helps me

Comment: The functions $f_n$ should help you there. But if you have a question about another exercise then post it as a new question please, and not in the comments.